# Implementation of the "Retail MAC" algorithm through the OpenSSL library on C

Tags: macos, algorithm, openssl, crc, des

I would be grateful if anyone could share an example of the implementation of the algorithm for calculating the checksum of a [Retail MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9797-1) using the OpenSSL library in C. I could not find nothing like this.
P.S. I'm sorry for my English

Comment: Your English is good.   You might want to post an example of what you have tried that has not worked, so we have some context.

Comment: I'm afraid that my program is simply not completely written, because I do not understand the functions of the openssl library. For this, I need some source of this algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The Retail MAC uses two single DES-Keys (8 bytes): K1 and K2. Let e.g., K1=`0110213041506170` and K2=`8190A1B0C1D0E1F0` (in hex).

Let M the message to be MACed, e.g., M="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".

M0 is then the padded message (don't use the OpenSSL block padding!)
`6162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F707172737475767778797A800000000000` (in hex).

Use OpenSSL as follows:

```
openssl enc    -des-cbc -K 0110213041506170 -iv 0000000000000000 -nopad -in M0 | \
tail -c 8 | \
openssl enc -d -des-ecb -K 8190A1B0C1D0E1F0 -nopad | \
openssl enc    -des-ecb -K 0110213041506170 -nopad | \
xxd -p -u -c32
```

Enjoy the MAC `468BB08720DAC59E`.

Off topic: Keep in mind that Retail MAC is considered broken.